# Hovering over a thumbnail triggers audio but not video using the YouTube API in JavaScript - how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am trying to make a YouTube video play when I hover on a thumbnail
But it only plays the audio, I can't see the video and it doesn't stop playing when I stop hovering.

Here is the code

HTML

```html
<div class="thumbnail" data-video-id="D9N7QaIOkG8">
    <img src="assets\meyra.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 1">
    <div class="video-overlay"></div>
</div>

<script>
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    const thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");

    thumbnails.forEach(function(thumbnail) {
      const videoOverlay = thumbnail.querySelector(".video-overlay");
      const videoId = thumbnail.dataset.videoId;

      thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
        const player = new YT.Player(videoOverlay, {
          videoId: videoId,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          playerVars: {
            autoplay: 1,
            controls: 0,
            rel: 0,
            showinfo: 0
          }
        });

        videoOverlay.style.display = "block";
      });

      thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
        videoOverlay.innerHTML = "";
        videoOverlay.style.display = "none";
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

I want a video to cover up the thumbnail just like a preview in youtube when I hover and stop playing when the mouse stops hovering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is once you mouseover, youtube replace your **.videoOverlay** div with iframe. So the reference you selected in **videoOverlay** variable will no longer work for showing and hiding.

You need to replace

```
videoOverlay.style.display = "block";
```

With

```
this.querySelector('.video-overlay').style.display = "block";
```

Do the same thing inside mouseleave event handler

```
this.querySelector('.video-overlay').innerHTML = "";
this.querySelector('.video-overlay').style.display = "none";
```

EDIT:
To interact with video object, (like you need to play or stop video), then you need to get a reference of player like below.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  const thumbnails = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbnail");

  var player;
  thumbnails.forEach(function(thumbnail) {
    const videoOverlay = thumbnail.querySelector(".video-overlay");
    const videoId = thumbnail.dataset.videoId;

    thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
      player = new YT.Player(videoOverlay, {
        videoId: videoId,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        playerVars: {
          autoplay: 1,
          controls: 0,
          rel: 0,
          showinfo: 0
        }
      });

      this.querySelector('.video-overlay').style.display = "block";
    });

    thumbnail.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
      this.querySelector('.video-overlay').innerHTML = "";
      this.querySelector('.video-overlay').style.display = "none";
      player.destroy();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting an marking as answer if it helped.

Comment: The video is still playing even after remove the mouse from the thumbnail.
How do i make it stop when i'm not hovering